# Use and Meaning of 'to be the last one'

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

I saw a friend's (A) picture on a social network. And a friend (B) of hers commented on it. Apparently (B) was having her finals exams , so (A) remarked "you should be the last person to comment on my picture, log out and study". My question , this expression" to be the last one" , is it correctly used here? And it means that she should rather be studying. Am I right?

Comment: Is A in fact a native speaker? It's a "recognizable" variant in the sense that there's no problem *understanding* the phrasing, but I'm not sure I've ever encountered it before. Standard phrasing would be *""You're **the last person who should** be commenting..."* Rearranging that to ***you should be the last person*** almost seems to imply B *should* actually comment (but just make sure he waits until everyone else has commented, so as to ensure *his* comment appears last in the list).

Answer (score 5):

Normally, this usage of *last* is admonitory and perhaps critical. It's used to set someone down who may be reaching above or beyond what may be deemed appropriate or proper.

For example, if an overweight person criticized someone's eating of a second helping of pie, that person might say

> You're the last person who should be telling me how to eat.

In other words, because of the person's own weight, he may be unqualified to pronounce judgment on others.

Lack of qualification and hypocrisy are the two most likely conditions to elicit that response. Consider:

> Priests are the last people who should advise married couples about their problems. [Priests are forbidden to marry]
>
> Politicians are the last people who should scream about corruption. [Politicians are largely seen as participating in corruption.]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, grammatically and semantically.  As for eitquette, it largely depends on how intimate you are.

Answer (score 1):

[Used for referring](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/last) to someone or something that remains *after all the rest have gone*, or to part of an amount that remains after the rest has been used.

- I wouldn't marry him if he was the *last* *man* on earth.
- You would be the *last* *person* to comment on my picture

Comment: But this doesn't address the pragmatics involved. Robusto's answer is correct.